# How to order by a variable in a recursive query and return the corect order?

Tags: mysql, sql

[Sql Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eH3ZuHniZoT2uux8kmhHGR/0)

I have the following structure and query

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    val varchar(255),
    parent INT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO test (id ,val ,parent) VALUES
(1 ,'Val_1', NULL),
(2, 'Val_2', 1),
(3, 'Val_3', 1),
(4, 'Val_4', 2),
(5, 'Val_5', 3), 
(6, 'Val_6', 1); 

 SET @count = 1;
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
SELECT 
id,
val,
parent,
@count
FROM
test
WHERE id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT
b.id,
b.val,
b.parent,
@count := @count + 1
FROM test b
INNER JOIN cte ON b.parent = cte.id
)

select * from cte order by @count asc;
```

```
SET @count = 1;
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT id, val, parent, @count
    FROM test
    WHERE id = 1
UNION ALL
    SELECT b.id, b.val, b.parent, @count := @count + 1
FROM test b
    INNER JOIN cte ON b.parent = cte.id
)

select * from cte order by @count asc;
```

I have a Parent-child relation on a table and I want to increment a variable depending on different cases, I have managed to set a variable and increment in each recursion but when ordering by the variable the order is wrong.

I know the documentation specifies that:

> *HAVING, GROUP BY, and ORDER BY, when referring to a variable that is
> assigned a value in the select expression list do not work as expected
> because the expression is evaluated on the client and thus can use
> stale column values from a previous row.*

But I don't really understand what that means.

So, why is the order wrong is this case, and is there a way I can order by the variable and make it return the 'correct' order ? This way I could avoid creating another column just for the order.

If I order by the parent column the order is 1-1-1-2-3, Why doesn't it work when  I try to order by the `@count` so they appear in order of the count 1-2-3-4-5...
Also, when running the query multiple times and ordering by the `@count` variable the order changes.

Is there another way I can create a value that is not in the database so I can use it for ordering ?

Comment: @variables are what we used prior to the arrival of windowing functions an cte

Comment: SQL is a declarative language. MySQL variables are now an obsolete solution that used imperative logic in queries. Please explain what's the expected result you want.

Comment: @TheImpaler I want to have a counter that increments with each iteration of the recursive query, I need it for ordering parent-child, everything works but when ordering by counter the columns appear out of order 5-6-1-2. 

And now I've seen that sometimes the order does work, but when I run the query multiple times it changes, I don't know why

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @forpas I want to get the columns ordered by the `@count` variable

Comment: The variable is not reliable as you found out, because its behavior is not consistent. Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dbbdf2852e6c75f6d0d95ba0160f30d5 where it seems to work. So if you explain your requirement maybe there is a solution without the variable.

Comment: @forpas I want to order all children under their parents, if a parent has 3 children show all children under the parent if the children have children show them under their child-parent and so on. This would have worked if the variable would have worked as I thought. Is there another way to generate a temporary value that I can use for ordering ? This is part of a bigger query, I might not explaining it very well.

Comment: If a parent has 3 children and these 3 children are under their parent then the children of the children where will they be? After the last child of the initial parent? You don't explain clearly what you want. Post more sample data with more levels and also post your expected results to clarify. Preferably in a fiddle.

Comment: @Radu Can you add the expected result to the question. We mean, the specific resulting tabular data you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

You're sql is very close to what you need.

Renaming count to rlevel because count is a sql keyword ...

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte(id, val, parent, rlevel) AS (
    SELECT id, val, parent, 1
    FROM test
    WHERE id = 1
UNION ALL
    SELECT b.id, b.val, b.parent, cte.rlevel + 1
FROM test b
    INNER JOIN cte ON b.parent = cte.id
)

select * from cte order by rlevel asc;
```